# Save option selected from a floating context menu in a bundle

Tags: android, menu, bundle

I'm programming an app and currently thinking of using a bundle to save the selected option of a floating context menu so it can appear in the next activity.It should go like this:

1.- Click a button, then the floating context menu should appear.

2.- Select an option.

3.- Start the second activity.

4.- The name of the option selected should appear in a textbox / EditText in the new activity.

Up to the third step, it's pretty easy, but I don't know how to make the 4th one. Can anyone tell me please how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your activity hosts a fragment, you can pass the information to the fragment using `setArguments(Bundle)`, which will allow you to bundle up the information and retrieve it when the view is created. The advantage to such an implementation means that the activity you send data to can be used for multiple things (where using an `Intent` would indicate that the activity has a sole purpose, and cannot be easily re-used)

```
// private method called during option select...
private void onOptionClickDoSomething() {
    Fragment myFragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequence("key", someStringValue);

    myFragment.setArguments(args); // attach args to the Fragment

    // invoke a transaction
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();  // assume using support library
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.myFragmentContainer, myFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Then in `MyFragment`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(...);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    // use these args to get your text value

    String myText = args.getCharSequence("key", "default");

    // ... more stuff

    return v;
}
```

Of course you could always use the intent to pass in the info directly to the activity:

```
// private method called during option select...
private void onOptionClickDoSomething() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", someStringValue);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In `MyActivity`, you can just get the `Intent` and look at the info there:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent i = getIntent();

    String myText = i.getExtra("key");

    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your option selected you will be creating an Intent correct? So pass the string along with the intent and then you can extract it in your next activity.

Add the string to your intent:

```
intent.putExtras("key", "string");
```

Then get the string in the next activity:

```
String string = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```